# How to adjust minibuffer-message?

Tags: emacs, sweave

I use

```lisp
(add-hook 'Rnw-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
         '("Sweave" "R CMD Sweave %s"
           TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run Sweave") t)
    (setq TeX-command-default "Sweave")))
```

to "Sweave" .Rnw files. After weaving is done, the minibuffer shows: "Sweave: done.". How can I change this message? I couldn't figure out where this message is created and how I can change it.